# how to change a css background onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manukurakar/8m9qstg3/1/), Here there are two div named `step-wrapper`  and inside these `step-wrapper` div there are three div named `step-box`. Its written in such a way that while clicking on a `step-box` div its background color changes to yellow.

I have added a reset button. What I needed is on clicking the reset button, the color of last clicked `step-box` div should changes to white. But in this code, when I click the reset button all the step-box background color changes to white.

Comment: So you want it more to behave like an undo button?

Comment: use jquery addclass and removeclass methods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:
https://jsfiddle.net/richardgirges/8m9qstg3/11/

We're saving a reference to the `lastClicked` div, and targeting it specifically when `reset` is hit. Like so:

```
var $lastClicked = null;

$('.step_wrapper').on('click','.step_box',function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.step_box').css('background-color', '');
    $(this).css('background-color', '#fff000');
    $lastClicked = $(this);
});


$('.reset').on('click',function(){
    if ( $lastClicked ) {
        $lastClicked.css( 'background-color', '#fff' );
        $lastClicked = null;
    }
});
```

EDIT: Improved the code. Using explicit `var` instantiation to keep it within scope.

Comment: Though I'd recommend `var lastClicked` instead of `$lastClicked`

Comment: Why? In my opinion, it makes perfect sense to use `$` for this variable. You can easily see if something's a jQuery object now. Use `var $variable` for jQuery objects, and `var variable` for all the other stuff.

Comment: I think it should be var $lastClicked. I just updated the code.  $lastClicked makes sense because you can tell it's a jQuery object like @Mave stated. But `var` should've been there from the get-go. That was a mistake on my part. Code is updated.

Comment: @Mave, right, sorry, `var $lastClicked`, not just `window.$lastClicked`

Answer (score 2):

It looks kind of weird when you have only one reset button at the very end but only want to reset only one wrapper.  How about if we add a reset button inside the wrapper div and resets only that wrapper when we click each reset?  See if you like it.

HTML:

```
<div class="step_wrapper">
<div class="step_box" onclick="show('Page1');"> <span>Content of page 1</span>

    </p>
</div>
<div class="step_box" onclick="show('Page2');"> <span>Content of page 2</span>

    </p>
</div>
<div class="step_box" onclick="show('Page3');"> <span>Content of page 3</span>

    </p>
</div>
<div class="reset"> Reset </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>Second Wrapper
    <br>
        <br>
 <div class="step_wrapper">
 <div class="step_box" onclick="show('Page1');"> <span>Content of page 1</span>

    </p>
</div>
<div class="step_box" onclick="show('Page2');"> <span>Content of page 2</span>

    </p>
</div>
<div class="step_box" onclick="show('Page3');"> <span>Content of page 3</span>

    </p>
</div>
<div class="reset"> Reset </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.step_wrapper').on('click','.step_box',function () {
$(this).parent().find('.step_box').css('background-color', '');
$(this).css('background-color', '#eeffaa');
});


$('.reset').on('click',function(){
$( this ).parent().find(".step_box").css( 'background-color', '' );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add class last to last clicked element and reset this one.

```
$('.step_wrapper').on('click','.step_box',function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.step_box').css('background-color', '');
    $(this).css('background-color', '#fff000');
    $('.last').removeClass('last');
    $(this).addClass('last');
});


$('.reset').on('click',function(){
    $( ".step_box.last" ).css( 'background-color', '' );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8m9qstg3/7/

Answer (score 1):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/8m9qstg3/8/)

What I have done is that, I've added an `ID` attribute to your `step_box` class and used the `id` to set a hidden field when the `step_box` is clicked. And later in the onClick of reset, i ve used the id that is set in the hidden field.

Please the code below..

**JS**

```
$('.step_wrapper').on('click','.step_box',function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.step_box').css('background-color', '');
    $(this).css('background-color', '#fff000');
    document.getElementById('test').value=this.id;
});


$('.reset').on('click',function(){
    var a= document.getElementById('test').value;
    $( "#"+a ).css( 'background-color', '' );

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="step_wrapper">
    <div class="step_box" onclick="show('Page1');" id="1"> <span>Content of page 1</span>

        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="step_box" onclick="show('Page2');" id="2"> <span>Content of page 2</span>

        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="step_box" onclick="show('Page3');" id="3"> <span>Content of page 3</span>

        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>Second Wrapper
<br>
<br>
<div class="step_wrapper">
    <div class="step_box" onclick="show('Page1');" id="4"> <span>Content of page 1</span>

        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="step_box" onclick="show('Page2');" id="5"> <span>Content of page 2</span>

        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="step_box" onclick="show('Page3');" id="6"> <span>Content of page 3</span>

        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="test" />
<div class="reset">Reset</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/8m9qstg3/6/

I created a variable named last and assigned the clicked object to it. This way, when you hit reset, it will know what the last element is that was clicked. If you're looking for multiples you could create an array and use `.push()` to create a string of last elements clicked, but this should answer your question.

```
var last;

$('.step_wrapper').on('click','.step_box',function () {
$(this).parent().find('.step_box').css('background-color', '');
$(this).css('background-color', '#fff000');
last = this;
});


$('.reset').on('click',function(){
$(last).css("background-color", "white");
});`
```